# /kill command not working in 1.9 with entitys with a name too long

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So basically, What i am trying to do is kill an armor stand who's name is "Wood Age - Farming". I am in 1.9

I have spawned him in with this command

**/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:Wood Age - Farming,CustomNameVisible:1}**

and i Have tried killing it with this one

**/kill @e[name=Wood Age - Farming]**

but it gives me this error

**The entity UUID provided is in an invalid format.**

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Target selectors do not support using spaces. You will either have to rename the armor stand to exclude spaces, assign it score/"tag" based on its name, or just assign it tags directly via `/summon` since you're using 1.9 anyway:

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"Wood Age - Farming",CustomNameVisible:1,Tags:["WoodAgeFarming"]}
```

The `/kill` command becomes:

```
/kill @e[type=ArmorStand,tag=WoodAgeFarming]
```

---

Otherwise, to assign a tag based on a pre-existing target's name:

```
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=ArmorStand,tag=!WoodAgeFarming] add WoodAgeFarming {CustomName:"Wood Age - Farming"}
/kill @e[type=ArmorStand,tag=WoodAgeFarming]
```

Or a score:

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=ArmorStand] OBJECTIVE 1 {CustomName:"Wood Age - Farming"}
/kill @e[type=ArmorStand,score_OBJECTIVE_min=1]
```